# What is the equation for this graphed function?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, step-function

I can't seem to figure out the equation for this simple function, I know that the equation for a vertical line is x = k but this looks like a kind of step function that is infinity when x = k.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of infinity, there would have been an asymptote. Nothing can be ever **equal to infinity**. It can **tend to infinity** when the variable tends to some value. Moreover, the exact function for the given graph would be

x = 2, y>0.

Comment: so does this mean that for x = 2, y = any value greater than zero? or y tends to infinity?

Comment: Any real value greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: This isn't a function.

Answer (score 1):

Well it doesn't qualify the criteria to be called function. For a relation to be a function any point in the domain must have a unique image. So, it is not a function however it is a relation x=2